# How to remove Zero-width non-joiner from string?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, hex

I have one string in PHP script

$str="इन रिकॉ‌र्ड्स पर है सलमान की नजर, धूम-3 को पछाड़ेगी जय हो?";

and converting it from below code:

```
$encoded_string = bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-16BE", 'UTF-8'));
```

**Output at Mobile Device :**

**इन रिकॉ‌(Here Zero-Width Non-Joiner is displaying in output)र्ड्स पर है सलमान की नजर, धूम-3 को पछाड़ेगी जय हो?**

but getting **Zero-Width Non-Joiner** **‌** in final output. how can i will remove this entity while converting string not after getting final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found Solution , Just replace **Zero-Width Non-Joiner** entity from String and it will works.

```
 $str=str_replace('&#8204;','',$str);

     **OR**  

 $str=str_replace('&zwnj;','',$str;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = preg_replace( '/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', $content );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = preg_replace( "/\x{200c}/u", '', $content );
```

Comment: thanks for the help, encountered this issue when did `preg_replace`

Comment: This helped me solve my problem. I saw a hint earlier in [unicode chart](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) that 0x200C is the ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER. did the preg_replace and poof!

Comment: This is the correct regex if "real" zero-width non-joiner characters are in the string. Other solutions assume that the character has already been escaped for HTML output.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I solve it by Using Regular Expression

```py
    import re
    mystring = "Hello W&zwnj;e"
    mystring  = re.sub(r"&lrm;","",mystring)
    mystring  = re.sub(r"&zwnj;","",mystring)
```

`&zwnj` = Zero-width non-joiner
`&lrm` =  Left-to-right mark